# MATLAB – Fastest way to stack and display TIFs

Tags: matlab

I have around 22 .tif images that I need to stack together. So far, my process for combining these images has been very manual and labor intensive as shown below. Is there a faster way to stack the .tif images without all this work?

[image]

Also, my second question is that when I do the `imshow` command, it only displays 8% of the final .tif image because the full image is 4000px by 4000px. Is there anyway to download the stacked .tif image onto my computer for further reference?

Comment: is the final image supposed to be 4000px^2?  if not `imadd(...)` may not be working correctly.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have all of your images as separate variables?  Why not consolidate them into a single 3-D or 4-D array?

Comment: @Matt So, there are 22 separate photo files and I'm essentially just superimposing them on each other. These photos were taken as slices of a 3D cell from an electron microscope and I need to put these "slices" together, so I used the `imadd` function.

Comment: @rayryeng You're right, I don't need them as separate variables. I used them as separate variables because I don't know any other method and also the only way to use the `imadd` function with 22 images is to put separate variables since the default MATLAB variable is `ans`.

Comment: Sorry that may not have been clear, are the individual images also 4000x4000px before being added together?

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things.

Comment: To answer the second part, it depends on OS, if you are using Mac and/or Linux systems `scp` would be a quick way to copy it, but ultimately it is the same as copying any file from a remote system to a local system.

Comment: @Shrey do you simply need all the images to be stacked, or is there a chance you need some different permutations?

Comment: @milez I need all the images to be stacked

Comment: why you didn't accept the good answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to store the images in an array then loop though the array, as is [demonstrated in this answer on the Mathworks website](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/77062-how-to-store-images-in-a-single-array-or-matrix).  once the images are in the array you can cycle through it.  [This example from the MATLAB FAQ](http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_process_a_sequence_of_files.3F) has some information about processing a list of files.

Assuming that the `imread(...)` command is used to make a-v at some point, and that it is used in a loop, an additional composite image could be generated when the files are being processed as part of that loop.